# Masonry rearrange while still resizing

Tags: javascript, responsive-design, transition, jquery-masonry

I'm using Masonry for arranging tiles on a page which can change width of the container in various steps due to responsive design. But while I'm actively resizing the browser masonry doesn't rearrange the icons. So in the worst case when I'm very slowly but steady resizing the browser with the masonry just stays stuck and frozen which just doesn't look very good or fluid.

Is there any workaround to get masonry to instantly react, even if there is a resizing still in motion?

Comment: im having the same issue,  can anyone lend a hand?

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide some more details regarding your specific situation?  It would be very helpful if you could show which libraries you're using as well as a url, or at the very least some code.

As a shot in the dark, my first reaction would be to check and make sure you're binding to the event listener window `resize` so that Masonry is told when it needs to reshuffle.

I've used [Desandro's Masonry Plugin](https://github.com/desandro/masonry) before, and in doing so you must bind to the `resize` event listener.  From the documentation:

> msnry.bindResize()
>
> > `$container.masonry('bindResize');`
> >
> > Binds event listener to window resize, so layout is triggered when the browser window is resized.